# How to remove the Windows waste basket icon from the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, icons

I have the Windows waste basket icon on the Windows taskbar (which is aligned on the left side of the desktop):

[image]

How can I remove the waste basket from the taskbar?

I have unchecked the waste basket checkbox in the desktop icons dialog box:

[image]

But the waste basket icon is still there on the taskbar. How can I remove it?

Edit: Found the culprit.

Comment: Right click on it and remove.

Comment: Also could try right clicking on the taskbar, hover over toolbars, and see if there is a Recycle Bin entry

Comment: Thanks to all. But I found the culprit: It was the program "Actual Window Manager" (an otherwise very useful tool) which had placed the Recycle Bin on the Windows taskbar. Now I have removed it from the settings. - Will delete this question in a few hours.

Comment: @user1580348 - You should answer the question instead of removing it which will eventually lead to a question ban